# Compound layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a custom layout to reduce redundancy in the code. Currently every layoutfile has about 30 Lines of code which are identical.

My goal was to create a custom layout/view which can hold in itself children.

```
<BaseLayout xmlns:...>
   <!-- Normal Content -->
   <Button /> 
   <Label /> 
</BaseLayout>
```

While the above xml holds most of the content, the BaseLayout is in itself an xml containing other views and functionality:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:...>
   <LinearLayout><!-- contains the Header--></LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout><!-- INDIVIDUAL CONTENT HERE--></LinearLayout>

   <FrameLayout><!-- contains the loading screen overlay --></FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So all children from the above xml should be inserted into second linear-layout. I have already succeeded into doing so. But am confronted with layout problems (match parents does not match parents and only wraps)

My approach was extending the LinearLayout with following logic:

```
/**
 * extracting all children and adding them to the inflated base-layout
 */
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.base_layout, null);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.base_layout_children);
    while(0 < getChildCount())
    {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        removeViewAt(0);
        linearLayout.addView(child, layoutParams);
    }
    this.addView(view);
}
```

---

Is there a better, cleaner approach to capsule the xml and reuse a basis layout? How do I fix the match_parent issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**While writing this post and thinking hard how to explain best, the solution for the match_parent issue became clear. Though the question remains if there is a better approach for the whole problem.**

```
//Solution:
this.addView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

//wrong:
this.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two layout files. common_views.xml and layout_main.xml. You can include content of one layout file into another like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/common"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            layout="@layout/common_views" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/common"
           >
        </WebView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```